# Typo? $H$ is quaternion algebra and $C$ is complex number. $M_n(H)\cong M_{2n}(C)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, geometry, differential-geometry, lie-groups

Denote $H$ as quaternion algebra and $C$ as complex number. 
Take any $a\in H$. One has $a=(a_1+ia_2)+(a_3+ia_4)j=c_1+jc_2$ with $ij=k$. Denote $M_n(F)$ as the matrix entries in division algebra $F$.

The book says $M_n(H)\to M_{2n}(C)$ is isomorphic. If this is true, then this must hold for $n=1$. So $H\cong M_{2}(C)$ as ring.

This homomorphism is given as the following. Using $c_1,c_2$ notation in first paragraph and labeling $x\in M_{2n}(C)$ as $x_{11},x_{12},x_{21},x_{22}$, I have $x_{11}=c_1,x_{12}=c_2,x_{21}=-\bar{c_2},x_{22}=\bar{c_1}$ where $\bar{x}$ denotes complex conjugation.

It is clear that this map is $R-$linear. So this had better to be isomorphic as $R-$vector space to start with even before talking about ring isomorphism.

Counting dimension over $R$ is $4\times 2=8$ for $M_{2}(C)$ and $H$ is only $4$. This cannot be isomorphism.

$\textbf{Q:}$ Is this a typo in the book? What is the correction? I could see it has to be identified to the image and this is clearly injection for sure.

Ref. D. Bump Lie Groups Chpt 5 Exercise 5.6

Comment: It is indeed a typo or imprecision of language. The map is an isomorphism _to_its_image_. That is all that's asserted, and you already see that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am almost sure what is meant there is that it is an isomorphism **to its image**. Namely, the map is obviously not surjective. But you can check that it is an injective morphism of $\Bbb R$-algebras. Indeed, the case $n=1$ gives a standard representation of the quaternions as **sub-$\Bbb R$-algebra** of $M_2(\Bbb C)$.